# how can i detect hebrew characters both iso8859-8 and utf8 in a string using php

Tags: php, regex, hebrew

I want to be able to detect (using regular expressions) if a string contains hebrew characters both utf8 and iso8859-8 in the php programming language. thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here's [map of the iso8859-8 character set](http://www.langbox.com/codeset/iso8859-8.html).  The range E0 - FA appears to be reserved for Hebrew.  You could check for those characters in a character class:

```
[\xE0-\xFA]
```

For UTF-8, the [range reserved for Hebrew](http://www.alanwood.net/unicode/hebrew.html) appears to be 0591 to 05F4.  So you could detect that with:

```
[\u0591-\u05F4]
```

Here's an example of a regex match in PHP:

```
echo preg_match("/[\u0591-\u05F4]/", $string);
```

Comment: The problem is that E0-FA are also values that will occur in UTF-8, but not nessescarily as hebrew characters...

Comment: @gnud: That's why you should not use the iso8859-8 regex on UTF-8 strings

Answer (score 7):

well if your PHP file is encoded with UTF-8 as should be in cases that you have hebrew in it, you should use the following RegX:

```
$string="אבהג";
echo preg_match("/\p{Hebrew}/u", $string);
// output: 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a small function to check whether the first character in a string is in hebrew:

```
function IsStringStartsWithHebrew($string)
{
    return (strlen($string) > 1 && //minimum of chars for hebrew encoding
        ord($string[0]) == 215 && //first byte is 110-10111
        ord($string[1]) >= 144 && ord($string[1]) <= 170 //hebrew range in the second byte.
        );
}
```

good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

First, such a string would be completely useless - a mix of two different character sets?

Both the hebrew characters in iso8859-8, and each byte of multibyte sequences in UTF-8, have a value `ord($char) > 127`. So what I would do is find all bytes with a value greater than 127, and then check if they make sense as is8859-8, or if you think they would make more sense as an UTF8-sequence...

Comment: How can a character have ord($char) > 255 in ISO-8859-8?  It's a single byte!

Comment: Well well. I don't know why, but I completely fudged that - non-ascii are between 128 and 255 - fixed now.

Comment: I figured that was what you meant in the mean time.  You're lucky I waited before downvoting you ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
function is_hebrew($string)
{
    return preg_match("/\p{Hebrew}/u", $string);
}
```