# How to tell if a string contains characters in Hebrew using PHP?

Tags: php, regex, hebrew

Trying to figure out how to tell whether a string contains *any* characters in Hebrew with no luck.

How can this be done?

Comment: I thinks this link will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694350/how-can-i-detect-hebrew-characters-both-iso8859-8-and-utf8-in-a-string-using-php

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*If* the source string is UTF-8 encoded, then the simpler approach would be using [`\p{Hebrew}`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) in the regex.

The call also should have the `/u` modifier.

```
 = preg_match("/\p{Hebrew}/u", $string)
```

Comment: Doesn't this miss a `\` in `\\p`?

Comment: @fge: If you want to be super correct :) But `"\p"` is no C-string escape, so will correctly reach the PCRE library as `\p`

Comment: Hmm, so you don't need to escape backslashes in PHP's string literals? I didn't know that.

Comment: @fge: There are only a few you need to escape. For example `"\r\n\t"`. Or otherwise use single quotes where all lose their special meaning.

Comment: Well yes, but here you use double quotes to surround `/\p{Hebrew}/u`. I didn't say the regex wasn't correct, I was simply guessing that a `\` was missing, no?

Comment: Yes, talking about PHP string escapes. In PHP double quotes only `"\n"` and `"\r"` get transliterated into linebreaks in the actual variable value. But `"\p"` has no special meaning, so will remain `\p` in the actual variable value. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double

Comment: OK, that makes sense! Gee, all languages seem to do that differently :p Thanks for your time!

Comment: No, worries. PHP is especially peculiar there. And just noticed the manual explains zilch. Will fix that tomorrow...

Answer (score 3):

[map of the iso8859-8 character set](http://www.langbox.com/codeset/iso8859-8.html).  The range E0 - FA appears to be reserved for Hebrew.

```
[\xE0-\xFA]
```

For UTF-8, the [range reserved for Hebrew](http://www.alanwood.net/unicode/hebrew.html) appears to be 0590 to 05FF.

```
[\u0590-\u05FF]
```

Here's an example of a regex match in PHP:

```
echo preg_match("/[\u0590-\u05FF]/", $string);
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest approach would be:

```
preg_match('/[א-ת]/',$string)
```

For example,

```
$strings = array( "abbb","1234","aabbאאבב","אבבבב");

foreach($strings as $string)
{
    echo "'$string'  ";

    echo (preg_match('/[א-ת]/',$string))? "has Hebrew characters in it." : "is not Hebrew";

    echo "<br />";
}
```